# Search a list and display answers in an Android app

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am in the process of creating an app that searches my text file for the given search term or acronym. This is the first app I have ever really created. The text file is formatted like: acronym%term%definition. I have a InputStream and a BufferedReader going through the file line by line. I then split it at the percent sign and put the strings into a triple using a Triple class I created and add that Triple to an ArrayList. My next function is supposed to search through the ArrayList of Triple for one that contains the search acronym or term. If it cannot find the acronym, it goes to the InvalidAcronym activity. If it is there, it goes to the ValidAcronym activity. For some reason, the only activity being triggered is the InvalidAcronym activity. I think it has something to do with adding the lines to the ArrayList. I originally had it working with just an acronym and definition using HashMaps. Can someone help me out? Here is my code:

```
package com.redacted.laurenanderson.acronymlookup;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.util.Pair;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Search extends AppCompatActivity{
    public EditText mEdit;
    public static String currAc;
   // public static HashMap<String,String> acros = new HashMap<String,String>(){{
    //add all currently known thingies.

//}};
public static ArrayList<Triple> acros2 = new ArrayList<Triple>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.acronyms2);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String[] str;
    //String FILENAME = "acronyms.txt";
    String FILENAME = "acronyms2.txt";



    try {
        String s = reader.readLine();
        while (s != null){
            //str = s.split(" ",2);
            //acros.put(str[0],str[1]);
            //THIS IS GOING TO BE THE REPLACEMENT
            str = s.split("%",3);
            System.out.println(str.toString());
            Triple<String,String,String> acro = new Triple<String,String,String>(str[0],str[1],str[2]);
            acros2.add(acro);
            s = reader.readLine();
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("OH NO");
        return;
    }


    mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.acroterm);
    //FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.home);
    //fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search);
    ImageButton fab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


         /*   if(acros.containsKey(mEdit.getText().toString())){
                currAc = mEdit.getText().toString();
               Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), ValidAcronym.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
            }
            else{
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), InvalidAcronym.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent2);
            }*/

           for( Triple triple: acros2){
                currAc = mEdit.getText().toString();
                if(triple.contains(currAc)){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), ValidAcronym.class);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
                }

            }
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), InvalidAcronym.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent2);


        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
/*public HashMap<String,String> getMap(){
    return acros;
}*/
public ArrayList<Triple> getList(){return acros2;}

/*public static Pair<String,String> returnAcro(String s){
    Pair<String,String> p = new Pair<String,String>(s,acros.get(s));
    //Triple<String,String,String> p = new Triple<String,String,String>(s, triple.second(),triple.third());
    return p;
}*/
public static Triple<String,String,String> returnAcro2(String s){
    for(Triple triple : acros2){
        if(triple.contains(s)){
            return triple;
        }
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: Just a thought, but I would put a return in that if statement, the one that starts your valid activity

Comment: Somehow that completely fixed the issue. You should put that as an answer so I can give you credit!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that both the activities are started. I have not run your code. But it seems that InvalidAcronym Activity starts after ValidAcronym and is therefore visible.

```
for (Triple triple: acros2) {
    currAc = mEdit.getText().toString();
    if (triple.contains(currAc)) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), ValidAcronym.class);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
    }

}
Intent intent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), InvalidAcronym.class);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent2);
```

After starting an activity, the execution doesn't stop. Therefore, it starts InvalidAcronym even after string matches. You can use a flag and break like shown below.

```
boolean flag = true;
for (Triple triple: acros2) {
    currAc = mEdit.getText().toString();
    if (triple.contains(currAc)) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), ValidAcronym.class);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}
Intent intent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), InvalidAcronym.class);
if (flag) {
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used a return and it works but this really helped me understand why it was happening.

Comment: Thanks. BTW return won't allow you to execute any further code after that for loop. In case you need to append something later in onCreate( ), you should you use break and flag or anything equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

So in the original code inside the onClickListener:

```
/*It goes through this loop */
for (Triple triple: acros2) {
    currAc = mEdit.getText().toString();
    /*Matches at the contains*/
    if (triple.contains(currAc)) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), ValidAcronym.class);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
        /*Starts The activity*/
    }
    /*Keeps Going*/
}
/*Still going*/
Intent intent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), InvalidAcronym.class);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent2);
/*Starts the InvalidAcronym activity, and shows it on top of everything will happen whether or not the acronym is valid*/
```

So to fix it:

```
for (Triple triple: acros2) {
    currAc = mEdit.getText().toString();
    if (triple.contains(currAc)) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), ValidAcronym.class);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
        /*end the onClick function early because it is valid and we don't need to keep going*/
        //This should show the correct activity now.
        return;
    }

}
//This won't be hit when it is valid
Intent intent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), InvalidAcronym.class);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent2);
```